# Change in Nav Bar Background When Scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I want to start out with the background transparent, and then for `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);` to transition for the navigation once the viewer starts to scroll down.

This is what I have so the html page pulls the js code.

```
<head>
<script src="nav.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

This is what I have for the navbar. I don't really want the whole `navbar` to change with scrolldown, just `inner`. The `logo` image needs to still be transparent.

```
 <nav class="navbar" >
    <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
    <div id="inner" id="top">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html" title="About">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here is my css (if more is needed I can post).

```
#inner{
width:140px;
float:right;
margin-right:5px;
text-align:justify;
}
.navbar a {
font-size: 14px;
font-family:SinkinSansLight;
letter-spacing:5px;
line-height: 20px;
border:none;
padding: 2px ;
text-decoration: none;
margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Finally, my js, which has been simply copy-pasted from other topics on SO, and adjusted with the ID from my css.

```
function checkScroll(){
var startY = $('#inner').height() * 2; //The point where the navbar changes in px

if($(window).scrollTop() > startY){
    $('#inner').addClass("scrolled");
}else{
    $('#inner').removeClass("scrolled");
}
}

if($('#inner').length > 0){
$(window).on("scroll load resize", function(){
    checkScroll();
});
}
```

Sorry there is so much, I just see a lot of people needed more code than supplied, and I have been trying a couple of options with js. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please post all the css relating to your avbar as well as the scrolled class too.

Comment: your 'inner' element has two id's? that's not valid html, an element should only have one unique id.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here, and your code should be working correctly. The `.scrolled` class should be added to `#inner` when the user scrolls down.

Comment: Well that code is live on tresart.net. Does the scroll feature work when you go to that website? I'm very confused why it won't work considering the code seems to be accurate. Also, fixed that second i'd you were talking about. Thanks for the catch! It wasn't even being used good to clean it up.

Comment: on tresart.net: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. you need to include jQuery in the page. http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: Found the problem. You're trying to use jQuery but haven't included it in the page. Put [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) on your site.**

I'm not really sure what you're asking because the jQuery code you posted works fine... It adds the class `scrolled` to `#inner` when the user scrolls.

Here is a snippet with your code. I added a transition to `#inner` and a background color to `#inner.scrolled` and set a height on the body so you can scroll and see it working.

```js
function checkScroll() {
  var startY = $('#inner').height() * 2; //The point where the navbar changes in px

  if ($(window).scrollTop() > startY) {
    $('#inner').addClass("scrolled");
  } else {
    $('#inner').removeClass("scrolled");
  }
}

if ($('#inner').length > 0) {
  $(window).on("scroll load resize", function() {
    checkScroll();
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
#inner {
  width: 140px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: fixed;
  transition: background-color 1s;
}
#inner.scrolled {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
.navbar a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: SinkinSansLight;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  line-height: 20px;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo">
  <div id="inner">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html" title="Home">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="about.html" title="About">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html" title="Contact">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: My css has the body set to `height: 100%;` so should that still work right? I'm not sure what is going on. The website I am trying to implement this on is tresart.net. If my code is accurate, could the page not be pulling the .js file properly?